# extend credibility to

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I have a question about the phrase "*extend credibility to*" in this [news article](http://www.marinij.com/article/NO/20160108/NEWS/160109853):

> “The defense feels frustrated, agonized and outraged — we feel that we have been stabbed in the back by this jury,” Serra told reporters after the verdict was handed down, noting Chow’s conviction was based on the testimony of “five snitches that no rational human being would believe or ***extend credibility to***.”

I could not find "*extend credibility to*" in dictionaries.  But I did find two similar sounding phrases "*extend credit to*" and "*lend credibility to*".  Could "*extend credibility to*" be slightly wrongly, because it came from an impromptu speech?

Comment: The speaker likely conflated the two phrases "lend credibility to" and "extend credit to"--as you suspect.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "lend credibility to" means to make an idea more believable: the object is the idea (theory, legal case).

> This new evidence **lends credibility to** the idea that he might actually be innocent

The phrase of "extend credit to" means to offer a loan to somebody: the object is a person.

> The bank would not **extend credit** to an unemployed person

Given that the speaker is talking about "the five snitches" (i.e. people), it seems reasonable to use the term **extend** rather than **lend**.

I don't know whether it's correct, but it's rational and I didn't notice the perceived problem whilst reading the text- only when I read the notes that followed. If it's a neologism, I think it's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

By parsing the phrase, I'm not recommending that you use it.

We **extend** something **to** someone, or **extend** {someone} {something}.

I can "extend you the benefit of the doubt". "Extend" there is just a synonym for "give" or "grant".   I can also "extend the benefit of the doubt to you." Same meaning, different syntax on the ditransitive.

To "grant someone credibility" (or to extend credibility to them) is to think they are, in general, "believable", that what they would say is "credible", to be believed.